# Como pegar uma URL completa usando Django?

Tags: python, django

Existe alguma função do Django que concatene um caminho específico com a URL base e retorne uma URL completa?

Exemplo:

```
url_completa = criar_url_completa("/meu_app/minha_view")
print(url_completa) # Resultado: https://meusite.com/meu_app/minha_view
```

Comment: Veja [`HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(location=None)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

Comment: Isso ajudou sim obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No settings.py tem um campo chamado ALLOWED_HOSTS, nele pode ser colocado o endereço do site em várias formas.

EX:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://meusite.com' , 'meusite.com']

Daí, vai na tua view onde quer pegar essa tua url base e importa o settings:

```
from django.conf import settings

url_completa = criar_url_completa("{}/meu_app/minha_view".format(ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]) 
print(url_completa) # Resultado: https://meusite.com/meu_app/minha_view
```